# sendto() returning -1 in server

Tags: sockets, unix, network-programming

```
int main()
{
   int servsocket,clientsocket;
   struct sockaddr_in server,client;
   FILE *file;
   char filename[100];
   char buf[1024];

    servsocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

    server.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port=htons(6003);
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;

    bind(servsocket,(struct sockaddr *) &server,sizeof(server) );

    while(1){   
        int clientsize=0;
        printf("Waiting for file requests \n");
       recvfrom(servsocket,filename,sizeof(filename),0,(struct          sockaddr *)&client,&clientsize);

     file=fopen(filename,"r");
     int size=0;

 do
 {
      size=fread(buf,1,sizeof(buf),file);
      printf("%d bytes read \n",size);
     int sentbytes=  sendto(servsocket,(const char *)buf,size,0,       (struct sockaddr *) &client,sizeof(client));
    printf("%d bytes sent ",sentbytes);         
    }while(size==sizeof(buf));  

   }
```

}

I am trying to make a simple program for file transfer using UDP. The problem is that sendto() always returns -1. This is the code for server.

Comment: When a system call returns -1 you're supposed to extract the `errno` value, call `perror(),` so that you *know* why it returned -1. Then you probably won't even have to ask the question here.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your code.  The one you're seeing is that you're not filling in the variable `client` properly: the `clientsize` parameter is used for both input and output by the `recvfrom` system call, so you need to initialise it to the size of the `client` structure:

```
int clientsize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
```

Another issue is that you're not 0-terminating the `filename` string:

```
n = recvfrom(...);
filename[n] = '\0';
```

Finally, you're not testing for errors (`bind`, `recvfrom`, `sendto`, etc.).  This will get you into trouble, I promise.

Comment: Actually I just have to make it work as quickly as possible,the final code will have proper error checking ,I just initialised the clientsize with size of client struct,i am now getting a segmentation fault. Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: @MohammedMuzammil Actually that is nonsense. The way to get it working as quickly as possible **is** to put in the proper error checking.